# How to apply an action all all open files except a particular one?

Tags: actions

I would like to apply an action to all open files except a particular one. An example: I have files A B C D opened, I want to apply the action on A-C but not D. Is there a way to limit this?

Comment: Close D seems the easiest way.

Comment: Does it not depend on the software in use *at all*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only apply an action to a single document or to all open documents in a batch.

Your options are:

1- Close D

2- If the action doesn't modify the original document, apply the action to all the documents and delete the output of D.

3- Put A, B and C in a folder and apply the action to the files in that folder.

Comment: 1. Is there a way to lock an open file for editing?
2. Is there a way to apply an action to all of the layers in a stack?

Comment: 1. Not as far as I know. 2. Yes, in your action you do Select / All Layers (Command + Option + A)